# How to get the list of active BP in IBM Sterling B2B Integrator

Tags: sql, oracle, ibm-sterling

How to get the list of active Business processes in IBM sterling B2B Integrator :

SQL for Oracle:

```
select DISTINCT NAME , WC2.WORKFLOW_ID, sysdate - START_T AS TIMEDIFF
From WORKFLOW_CONTEXT WC,
(
SELECT MAX(STEP_ID) STEP_ID , MIN(START_TIME) START_T, WORKFLOW_ID
FROM WORKFLOW_CONTEXT
GROUP BY WORKFLOW_ID
) WC2,
WFD
WHERE WC.WORKFLOW_ID = WC2.WORKFLOW_ID
AND WC.STEP_ID = WC2.STEP_ID
AND WC.NEXT_AI_ID != -1
AND WC.WFD_ID = WFD.WFD_ID
AND WC.WFD_VERSION = WFD.WFD_VERSION
AND BASIC_STATUS = 0
```